Placing linked collection creates empty
I'm using v3.6.1. When placing a linked collection, it adds an extra empty. How do I get rid of it?
TIA

It doesn't seem like you can get rid of the empty for a collection instance, you could CtrlA > Make Instances Real but the collection won't be linked anymore.
